# python JSON array newlines

Tags: python, json

I have a large dictionary that has some large array data in it:

```
d = {'something': {'else': 'x'}, 'longnumbers': [1,2,3,4,54,6,67,7,7,8,8,8,6,4,3,3,5,6,7,4,3,5,6,54]}
```

The real dictionary has many more keys and a nested structure. When I use `json.dump` without `indent`, I get a compact, single-line output which is not readable. When I set `indent`, it puts newlines after every separator, including the arrays.

The numerical arrays are long and end up like this:

```
  "longnumbers": [
    1, 
    2, 
    3, 
    4, 
    54, 
    6, 
    67, 
    7, 
    7, 
    8, 
    8, 
    8, 
    6, 
    4, 
    3, 
    3, 
    5, 
    6, 
    7, 
    4, 
    3, 
    5, 
    6, 
    54
  ],
```

Is there any way to get pretty-printed JSON with an indent level, but without placing newlines after array elements? For the example above, I'd like something like this:

```
{
  "longnumbers": [1, 2, 3, 4, 54, 6, 67, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 5, 6, 54],
  "something": {
    "else": "x"
  }
}
```

Comment: You will most likely need to code this yourself.

Comment: @NiklasB. that's the conclusion I came to when I had a similar issue. Fortunately, the `json` library is implemented in Python, and not especially hard to read, which provides a good base for things.

Comment: I think a good way would be to just wrap `json.dumps` and only override the behaviour for handling dicts, passing through all the other element types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@jterrace's answer was written for Python 2, which has since deprecated for Python 3 with changes to types. So, with all due credit to his answer, I tweaked it a tad bit for my personal use & compatibility with Python 3, including support for tuples as lists:

```py
import numpy

INDENT = 3
SPACE = " "
NEWLINE = "\n"

# Changed basestring to str, and dict uses items() instead of iteritems().
def to_json(o, level=0):
  ret = ""
  if isinstance(o, dict):
    ret += "{" + NEWLINE
    comma = ""
    for k, v in o.items():
      ret += comma
      comma = ",\n"
      ret += SPACE * INDENT * (level + 1)
      ret += '"' + str(k) + '":' + SPACE
      ret += to_json(v, level + 1)

    ret += NEWLINE + SPACE * INDENT * level + "}"
  elif isinstance(o, str):
    ret += '"' + o + '"'
  elif isinstance(o, list):
    ret += "[" + ",".join([to_json(e, level + 1) for e in o]) + "]"
  # Tuples are interpreted as lists
  elif isinstance(o, tuple):
    ret += "[" + ",".join(to_json(e, level + 1) for e in o) + "]"
  elif isinstance(o, bool):
    ret += "true" if o else "false"
  elif isinstance(o, int):
    ret += str(o)
  elif isinstance(o, float):
    ret += '%.7g' % o
  elif isinstance(o, numpy.ndarray) and numpy.issubdtype(o.dtype, numpy.integer):
    ret += "[" + ','.join(map(str, o.flatten().tolist())) + "]"
  elif isinstance(o, numpy.ndarray) and numpy.issubdtype(o.dtype, numpy.inexact):
    ret += "[" + ','.join(map(lambda x: '%.7g' % x, o.flatten().tolist())) + "]"
  elif o is None:
    ret += 'null'
  else:
    raise TypeError("Unknown type '%s' for json serialization" % str(type(o)))
  return ret
```

Comment: thank you and @jterrace ! This saves me a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 15):

I ended up just writing my own JSON serializer:

```
import numpy

INDENT = 3
SPACE = " "
NEWLINE = "\n"

def to_json(o, level=0):
    ret = ""
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        ret += "{" + NEWLINE
        comma = ""
        for k,v in o.iteritems():
            ret += comma
            comma = ",\n"
            ret += SPACE * INDENT * (level+1)
            ret += '"' + str(k) + '":' + SPACE
            ret += to_json(v, level + 1)

        ret += NEWLINE + SPACE * INDENT * level + "}"
    elif isinstance(o, basestring):
        ret += '"' + o + '"'
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        ret += "[" + ",".join([to_json(e, level+1) for e in o]) + "]"
    elif isinstance(o, bool):
        ret += "true" if o else "false"
    elif isinstance(o, int):
        ret += str(o)
    elif isinstance(o, float):
        ret += '%.7g' % o
    elif isinstance(o, numpy.ndarray) and numpy.issubdtype(o.dtype, numpy.integer):
        ret += "[" + ','.join(map(str, o.flatten().tolist())) + "]"
    elif isinstance(o, numpy.ndarray) and numpy.issubdtype(o.dtype, numpy.inexact):
        ret += "[" + ','.join(map(lambda x: '%.7g' % x, o.flatten().tolist())) + "]"
    elif o is None:
        ret += 'null'
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unknown type '%s' for json serialization" % str(type(o)))
    return ret
```

Comment: This function is free to use under a BSD license.

Comment: This answer saved my day!

Answer (score 4):

Ugh, should really be an option for specifying different indents for the two different JSON container types by now. An alternative approach if you want to stay compatible with the core Python JSON lib is to override the function (`_make_iterencode()` currently) in that lib that is responsible for handling `indent`.

Had a crack at [reimplementation of _make_iterencode()](https://github.com/sam-at-github/_make_iterencode.py). Only had to change a few [lines](https://github.com/sam-at-github/_make_iterencode.py/commit/7f87dd8d462aa30de97aeb52dbc594784e317bfa) to make the `indent` option, optionally take a tuple `(hash-indent, array-indent)`. But unfortunately have to replace an entire `_make_iterencode()` which turns out to be pretty big and poorly decomposed. Anyway, following works for 3.4-3.6:

```
import sys
import json

dat = {"b": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], "a": 1, "c": "x"}
indent = 2
print(json.dumps(dat, indent=indent))

if sys.version_info.major == 3 and 4 <= sys.version_info.minor <= 6:
  import _make_iterencode
  json.encoder._make_iterencode = _make_iterencode._make_iterencode
  indent = (2, None)

print(json.dumps(dat, indent=indent))
```

**Gives**:

```
{
  "c": "x",
  "a": 1,
  "b": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10
  ]
}
{
  "c": "x",
  "a": 1,
  "b": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}
```